# replace minus sign with brackets() using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

--html--

```
<table>
<tr>
<th>a</th>
<th>b<th>
</tr>
<tbody class = "tabledata">
<tr>a</tr>
<tr>b</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

--jquery--

```
 $('.tabledata').empty();
for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
                var abc = '<tr><td>' + result[i]['a'] + '</td><td>' + result[i]['b'] + '</td></tr>'
                //var results = abc.replace(/-(.*)/, "()");

                $('.tabledata').append(abc);
}
```

the result carries negetive values such as -245.1, -897.7. I want to change them as (245.1) and (897.7). I have tried .replace function but could not get it work.

Comment: Do you also want to wrap non-negative values with brackets?

Comment: no. positive values are not be written within brackets

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Math.abs` while creating the `abc` itself

```
var a  = "(" + Math.abs( result[i]['a'] ) + ")";
var b  = "(" + Math.abs( result[i]['b'] ) + ")";
var abc = '<tr><td>' + a + '</td><td>' + b + '</td></tr>'
```

Or do some refactoring to make the code less verbose

```
var fnAbs = ( s ) => "(" + Math.abs( s ) + ")";
var abc = '<tr><td>' + fnAbs( result[i]['a'] ) + '</td><td>' + fnAbs( result[i]['b'] )  + '</td></tr>';
```

if you don't want to wrap non-negative values with `()` then change `fnAbs` as

```
var fnAbs = ( s ) => +s < 0 ? "(" + Math.abs( s ) + ")" : s;
```

**Note**

`+s < 0`, converts `s` to **Number** before comparison in case s is of type `"string"`

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca Yes, added that too, Thanks.

Comment: This does assume all results would be negative and therefore need the brackets. Not sure if the poster needs non negative results returned without brackets. It wasn't clear.

Comment: Why does it not work in Internet Explorer. ECMAscript is not supported by IE. Can you suggest any other solution that is supported by all browsers? Thanks

Comment: Arrow functions are not supported by IE.